# Get min & max value from array every `id` depend on `date` PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, max, min

I need help for logic to get min & max value from an array for every id depend on date.

Here's the example of array :

```
$list_data  = array(
            array('20', '2016-08-04', '10:07:42'),
            array('20', '2016-08-04', '18:07:34'),
            array('35', '2016-08-05', '10:09:39'),
            array('35', '2016-08-05', '10:09:45'),
            array('35', '2016-08-05', '18:03:18'),
            array('35', '2016-08-05', '18:03:18'),
            array('39', '2016-08-05', '10:09:23'),
            array('39', '2016-08-05', '10:09:25'),
            array('39', '2016-08-05', '18:03:36'),
            array('39', '2016-08-05', '18:03:37'),
            array('35', '2016-08-08', '10:09:39'),
            array('35', '2016-08-08', '10:09:45'),
            array('35', '2016-08-08', '18:03:18'),
            array('35', '2016-08-08', '18:03:18'),
            array('39', '2016-08-08', '10:09:23'),
            array('39', '2016-08-08', '10:09:25'),
            array('39', '2016-08-08', '18:03:36'),
            array('39', '2016-08-08', '18:03:37'),
        );


index[0] = ID,
index[1] = Date,
index[2] = Time,
```

How i print the array

```
foreach($list_data as $data){
            echo $data[0];
            echo '<br>';
            echo $data[1];
            echo '<br>';
            echo $data[2];
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

Now, what i want is to find the `smallest time` and `biggest time` for every `ID` on every `Date`

Example list i want to show :

- ID '35' on '2016-08-05' SMALLEST TIME is '10:09:39';
- ID '35' on '2016-08-05' BIGGEST TIME is '18:03:18';
- ID '39' on '2016-08-05' SMALLEST TIME is '10:09:23';
- ID '39' on '2016-08-05' BIGGEST TIME is '18:03:37';

## Thank you

Conclusion : 
Caused list data of array comes from another machine (format date and time can not be changed into unixtimestamp), so this is how i avoid to use 'strtotime'.

Result :

function to convert date so i'm not using 'strtotime' function

```
function date_convert_to_time($date){
    $new_date   = new DateTime($date);
    return $new_date->format('U');
}
```

first group array

```
$arr = array();
// group them
foreach ($list_data as $v) {
    // first by id, then by date
    $arr[$v[0]][$v[1]][] = date_convert_to_time($v[1].' '.$v[2]);
}

// present it
foreach ($arr as $id => $sorted) {
    foreach ($sorted as $date => $times) {
        // $times = array_map('strtotime', $times); <--commented
        $smallest = date('H:i:s', min($times));
        $biggest = date('H:i:s', max($times));
        echo "ID '{$id}' on '{$date}' SMALLEST TIME is {$smallest}\n";
        echo "ID '{$id}' on '{$date}' BIGGEST TIME is {$biggest}\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to group the array first, group them by `ID`, then `Date`. Assign them in a new container as multi dimensional array, first level the `ID`, and on each `ID` each `Date`.

Idea:

```
$arr = array();
// group them
foreach ($list_data as $v) {
    // first by id, then by date
    $arr[$v[0]][$v[1]][] = $v[2];
}

// present it
foreach ($arr as $id => $sorted) {
    foreach ($sorted as $date => $times) {
        $times = array_map('strtotime', $times);
        $smallest = date('H:i:s', min($times));
        $biggest = date('H:i:s', max($times));
        echo "ID '{$id}' on '{$date}' SMALLEST TIME is {$smallest}<br/>";
        echo "ID '{$id}' on '{$date}' BIGGEST TIME is {$biggest}<br/>";
    }
}
```

Basically each time is designated to each date, just simply convert them to unix timestamp and as an array, just use `min` and `max` to get the lowest and highest.

[Sample Out](https://eval.in/900169)

Comment: On Progress to try, wait up

Comment: This work, and i combine a bit function to convert the time.

thx @Ghost

Comment: Sorry i can't give reputation yet, but great thanks for your help @Ghost

Comment: @AradeaTechno sure nob prob, glad this helped